# Learning resources for Minjiang dialect (岷江话)?

Tags: topolect, resources

[岷江话](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%B2%B7%E6%B1%9F%E8%AF%9D)

> 岷江话，又称为岷江小片，是四川话的一个分支，主要分布于四川盆地西南部岷江流域及长江两岸，同时在盆地中部分布有一个由西充、盐亭、射洪三县组成的方言岛。岷江话的主要特征是入声保留，独立成调，拥有一套仅用于入声字的紧元音韵母，在部分地区还保留有喉塞音韵尾，因而并不符合“入声归阳平”这一《中国语言地图集》中划定西南官话的标准。在《中国语言地图集》中，部分学者因其除入声外的声调调值与成渝片相近而仍将其划入西南官话[1](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%B2%B7%E6%B1%9F%E8%AF%9D)。但也有学者认为，岷江小片是由中上古巴蜀语直接发展而成，与主要源自移民的西南官话拥有截然不同的起源[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minjiang_dialect)。

[Minjiang dialect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minjiang_dialect)

> Minjiang dialect (simplified Chinese: 岷江话; traditional Chinese: 岷江話, local pronunciation: [min˨˩tɕiaŋ˥xa˨˨˦]; pinyin: Mínjiānghuà), is a branch of Sichuanese, spoken mainly in the Min River (Mínjiāng) valley or along the Yangtze in the southern and western parts of the Sichuan Basin. There is also a language island of Minjiang dialect located in the center of the Sichuan Basin covering three counties: Xichong, Yanting, and Shehong Counties.

There are resources listed on both wikipedia pages, but they are mostly just classification materials & not learning-based.

Are there any learning resources for Minjiang dialect (岷江话)?

The only things I know of are quite specific:

[乐山方言](https://book.douban.com/subject/1606436/)

[遵义方言语法研究](https://book.douban.com/subject/5398699/)

遵义方言诠注

[四川邛崃油榨方言记](https://book.douban.com/subject/4621060/)

Comment: 岷江话 is a very local language, it is hard to find any material to study that. The easiest way, I think, it go to that place and learn it from the local people, but any way, you must good at Chinese.

Comment: 为什么要学这个？你中文（书写）和普通话现在大概什么水平了？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some audio resources you can find online.

- [Four recital audios in 乐山方言 by a native speaker](http://i.youku.com/i/UMzk3NTQ2NTYxMg==?spm=0.0.0.0.2gJYWR), which maybe useful for audition.
- [A community of 岷江话](http://tieba.baidu.com/f?kw=%E5%B2%B7%E6%B1%9F%E8%AF%9D&ie=utf-8)：there are some resources

This is my first answer in the community, if my answer is not appropriate, please let me know. Thank you.